# What is the Context in this matter?

Tags: c#, android, file, xamarin

I am struggling to find the "Context" value in call this function like

```
SetFile("Name", ???, 1, "Some text here")
```

I have looked here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context but there seems to be a lot of possibilities and not clear to me which one I should use and how.
I have no idea what to fill in the "???" place, can anybody help me out on this?

```
public void SetFile(string BroadCastName, Context Context, long? DirectoryId, string BaseContent)
    {
        if (!BroadCastName.Contains(".enc"))
            BroadCastName = BroadCastName + ".enc";
        if (DirectoryId == null)
            DirectoryId = 2;
        var File = Directories.Where(x => x.Id == DirectoryId).FirstOrDefault().File;
        var Path = Directories.Where(x => x.Id == DirectoryId).FirstOrDefault().Path;
        File FilesDir = new File(Path, "SDDnode");
        FilesDir.Mkdir();
        if (bool.Equals(FilesDir.CanWrite(), true)) {
            File newFile = new File(FilesDir, BroadCastName);
            try
            {
                OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(Context.OpenFileOutput(BroadCastName, FileCreationMode.Private));
                outputStreamWriter.Write(BaseContent);
                outputStreamWriter.Flush();
                outputStreamWriter.Close();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                #region
                ledger._base.Errors.Add(new Error {
                    Message = "Something went wrong in generate file in Android",
                    Process = "sddnode_android.Base._system",
                    Sys_Message = e.Message,
                    Line = 115,
                    Priority = 1
                });
                #endregion
            }

            OutputStream os;
            try
            {
                os = new FileOutputStream(newFile);
                //target.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 100, os);
                os.Flush();
                os.Close();
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.PrintStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Context, Would likely refer to an ORM context. 
Like EF.
Or a context inregards to an AccessLayer, like IO AccessLayer.

Comment: What do you mean for question ?

Comment: An Android Context is typically an Activity or an Application subclass

Comment: To do this call SetFile("Name", ???, 1, "Some text here") I need to fill something in the place where now the 3 question marks, this I want to know

Comment: Yes I understood it is and Activity or Application, but I want to know which one

Comment: @Morton, do you know which one specific in this matter? Context.OpenFileOutput()

Comment: In terms of openFileOutput , either one will work, I'd would just use `ApplicationContext`

Comment: To be clear I look for an answer like this "SetFile("test", Context.AppOpsService, 2, "");"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get application context using

```
var currentContext = Android.App.Application.Context;
```

and then use it to pass in `setFile` method. Like,

```
SetFile("Name",currentContext, 1, "Some text here")
```

Comment: Ok that worked, thanks! But still not really understand the use of it as its not very logic if the Context is pretty much not very useful. But you saved my day frustration!

Comment: What mean by "not useful" ? Ask once its importance to Native Developer....

Comment: I mean in this context if you caan choose multple option (sorry I am not a Android developer)

Answer (score 1):

For that piece of code, there's really no way to find out where that Context came from, since we don't know what called it.

But, the highest possibility is an Activity context, due to the type of method it is, though a Service is also likely.

However, it really doesn't matter, since the only use of Context in that method is `Context.OpenFileOutput(BroadCastName, FileCreationMode.Private)` and this is something that can be done safely with a context from anywhere.

**Edit:**

To get the Context, you can simply use the `this` keyword inside an Activity or Service.

So wherever you want to run that method, you simply call `SetFile("test", MainActivity.this, 2, "");` Replace MainActivity with the class name of the Activity or Service you're using it in.

If you're using it in some other place outside of an Activity or Service, check to see if that component has a `getContext()` method.

Comment: the call be like this             SetFile("test", Context.AppOpsService, 2, ""); Can you help me out and give a code example?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Are you asking where to get the Context to use in the method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the context of the activity that is calling the SetFile method.

You can get a 
[good explanation of the context class in here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3572553/10916407)

Comment: Yes I saw this post but it still does not give me the sample or answer I need as its very confusing, I look for answer like this "SetFile("test", Context.AppOpsService, 2, "");"